# Kile: How can I insert repeated code snippet and make keyboard shortcut in kile for LaTeX?

Tags: macros, kile, code-snippets

To insert figures in LaTeX document I use this code repeatedly:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% figure environment start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[hb!]
\centering
\includegraphics [scale=0.35]{images/fig1.eps}
\caption{mycaption.}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% figure environment end %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Is there any way i can make macro of this code block and create a keyboard shortcut such as `CTRL+Shift+f` that automatically insert this code.

Or, could we write a snippet and so that i can insert this code block in KILE text editor.
I know how to make template in kile but what I need is shortcut key that inserts this piece of code automatically.

Maybe I can create a simple text file somewhere in kile directory and use it. But I don't know how to do this.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!
Related links:

- [Inserting text automatically with macros in Kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28691/inserting-text-automatically-with-macros-in-kile?rq=1)
- [Macro defining macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/macro-defining-macro?rq=1)
- [Search for most frequently occurring patterns in text (to replace them by macros)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101434/search-for-most-frequently-occurring-patterns-in-text-to-replace-them-by-macros?rq=1)
- [Declare macro for simple text snippets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121039/declare-macro-for-simple-text-snippets?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome! Since you already saw the questions concerning snippets, could you explain the problem? Why can't you just define the snippet and assign it a shortcut? That works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start selecting the desired text in a Kile document:

[image: highlighted text]

Keeping the text selected, choose Tools > Create Snippet from the menu to bring up the snippet creation dialogue:

[image: create snippet]

This allows you to specify the keyboard shortcut and other options of your choice.

Alternatively, choose Tools > Snippets... to create a snippet without basing it on text in the current document. In this case, you can just type the text from scratch into the dialogue box.

Tools > Snippets... also allows you to edit and manage existing snippets.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A small followup question, if i open a blank tex file in kile, can i insert previously defined templates into it. I know if i want a new template we can use those from kile but i don't know how to insert old templates into a new blank file?

Comment: Why don't you just select the relevant template rather than a blank one when you create the new file?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old and I could not find the *Create Snippet* windows suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303982/117801). Still, in Kyle version 2.9, one can use *User Tags*, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27391/117801). They can be found in the menu there:

```
LaTeX -> User-Tags -> Edit User Tags
```