# Repeatedly used snippets of code - how to shortcut?

Tags: code-snippets

I use LaTeX and TexStudio.

I work with transripts and have so far found \longtable to be my best friend, e.g.:

```
\begin{longtable}[H]{p{1.7cm}p{11.5cm}}
    Ignoramus  &  Richard, what are your favourite animals? \\
    Richard    &  Gnus, penguins and deers, of course! \\
    \caption*{(Animal talk)} 
\end{longtable}
```

I have to make (yet another) dozens of such dialogues. Soe of them are quite long - that's one reason to use longtable.

I have tried to figure out how I can make a macro or something to let me insert a template like:

```
\begin{longtable}[H]{p{1.7cm}p{11.5cm}}
       &   \\
    \caption*{()} 
\end{longtable}
```

but to no avail.

It seems that in

It seems that kileuser have this option: [Kile: How can I insert repeated code snippet and make keyboard shortcut in kile for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303920/kile-how-can-i-insert-repeated-code-snippet-and-make-keyboard-shortcut-in-kile)

What is the simple solution for a TexStudio user?

Comment: There is quite likely to be a better environment for this, or you can define your own.  There are also packages for typesetting dialogue (for example [`dialogue`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dialogue?lang=en)).

Comment: Unrelated: note that `[H]` doesn't do anything at all. A `longtable` doesn't float,  the optional argument can be `l`, `c` or `r` for determining horizontal alignment.

Comment: Regarding TeXstudio, have you seen Macros --> Edit Macros?

Comment: Thanks. I will check out the dialogue package. Still it doesn't solve my problem about repeatedly used snippets.

Comment: If I understand this correctly: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros, macros might help me to repeat text in the output file, but not in the code.

Comment: I just realised I was so wrong: The macro function can do exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: You could put your snippet in a separate file, copy and paste.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, do you mean in the sense that I should open two .tex files and then copy paste every time?

Comment: It depends on your editor, I have about 7 files open on mine right now.